# How many effects should I take in my regression model?

Tags: regression, predictor

I have two questions.

1. I know you shouldn't take too many covariates in your regression model. I have 3 continuous covariates available, and 3 group covariates available. Should I take them all? If not, what's the limit? I have $N > 1000$ data rows.
2. When I do take group covariates, do I always need to include interactions between groups? So, for example, if I take all 6 covariates, I am going to have 10 covariates (3 continuous, 3 main groups, 3 two-group interactions, and 1 three-group interaction). Or can I ignore some interactions?

Comment: please give details of  your outcome variable contnuous. depends on your model to ignore certain interactions.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking:

**1. Number of covariates:**
As a often used rule of thumb, you want at least 15 observations per covariate (and interaction effects). So in theory you *should* have enough observations to go around. That being said, special care needs to be taken with categorical data (which is what I understand from "group covariates"):
Categorical data needs breaking to $N_{categories}-1$ variables when entered into regression. Some statistical packages (e.g., R) will do that for you, others (e.g., SPSS) will not. So if you have a variable `country` with $170$ categories, that's $169$ variables that micro-divide your data, and eating up degrees of freedom.

**2. Interactions:** without further information it is difficult to say. However, you don't *have* to use interactions at all. Certainly, you are not obliged to interact your categorical variables with one another. Interactions have a specific meaning and can cause problems (such as multicollinearity) - especially with 3rd degree interactions. So it might be prudent to first think whether there is a theoretical justification to perform an interaction.